# Adding elements to TableViewer from a collection?

Tags: swt, jface, windowbuilder, tableviewer

So I'm trying to make a simple program that takes in some basic information about a loan, and turns it into an amortization table.

I am using WindowBuilder for this, and thus I have a Tableviewer that is supposed to have a column for Month, interest, payment, ect.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the table to actually display information. I have a Loan object that generates an ArrayList of month objects (each month being one row of the table), but from what I've read online, it's not as simple as telling the Tableviewer to populate each column with a variable from that arraylist.

I have set my Content Provider to be a Loan object, which contains an Arraylist of Month Objects, and each Month object has a getter for each column.

How do I go about displaying the text in each column?

Thanks.

EDIT:

So, here is the snippet of code from the example given to me below:

```
colFirstName.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
            Person p = (Person) element;
            return p.getFirstName();
    }});
```

I don't quite understand what is going on here. It's overriding the getText method, and casting the element to the type of element that has their data?

```
balanceCol.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
         @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                    Loan m = (Loan) element;
                    return m.getMonthObj().get(0).getMonth();
            }
    });
```

When I run this, it almost sorta works. It fills in about half the months, and then I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: model.Month cannot be cast to model.Loan
```

Comment: Use table column label providers. Read something like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html). Note that TableViewer is 'JFace' not plain SWT.

Comment: I have read through that, and I am getting stuck at the column label provider part. I have updated the original post so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Well somewhere you are trying to cast something that is a Month to Loan. I can't say any more than that from the small bits of code you have shown. We really need to see a [mcve]